# spring data mongodb enum mapping converter

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java

I would like code not throws exception when java code load enum value from mongo that not exists in enum code

Exemple :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant fr.myapp.type.OrderOptionEnum.TELEPHONE
at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getPotentiallyConvertedSimpleRead(MappingMongoConverter.java:819)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readCollectionOrArray(MappingMongoConverter.java:909)
at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1184)
```

Because TELEPHONE not existe in OrderOptionEnum

I juste want the code return null value

Any idea ?

Regards

Comment: I think you need to create a custom ConverterFactory:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/30024621/641627

Comment: This is old, but could be of help for you (he wraps his enum):  https://ghads.wordpress.com/2011/04/12/mongodb-and-java-enums

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add a custom converter implement `Converter<String, OrderOptionEnum>` there you implement your own convert logic from string to your enum.

something like this

```
public class OrderOptionEnumMongoConverter implements Converter<String, OrderOptionEnum> {

    @Override
    public OrderOptionEnum convert(String source) {

        for (OrderOptionEnum OrderOptionEnum : OrderOptionEnum.values()) {
            if (OrderOptionEnum.name().equals(source))
                return OrderOptionEnum;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

**Notice !!!** This converter will try to convert each string in mongo to your enum, thus may result in unwanted conversions, so make sure you do this only when needed.
you can add `@ReadingConverter` if you want this convert only when reading from mongo.