# Lowercase enum values from API to Mongo with Spring

Tags: rest, spring-boot, enums, spring-data-mongodb

Using Spring Boot, I'm exposing a REST API that accepts my domain object as a JSON body and attempts to persist it to a Mongo Document. How can I accept lowercase values of this enum in the JSON request **and** save them to Mongo as lowercase as well?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding accepting lowercase values of the enum, you can refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46382606/1781024)

Regarding saving them to MongoDB in lowercase as well, you need to write custom converters and register the same.

A typical write converter can be something like:

```
@WritingConverter
public final class YourEnumWriteConverter implements Converter<YourEnum, String> {
    @Override
    public String convert(YourEnum source) {
        return source == null ? "" : source.name().toLowerCase();
    }
}
```

You also need to write the corresponding read converter to read the lowercase string as enum successfully from DB. A typical read converter will look like:

```
@ReadingConverter
public final class YourEnumReadConverter implements Converter<String, YourEnum> {
    @Override
    public YourEnum convert(String source) {
        return source == null ? null : Arrays.stream(YourEnum.values()).
                                              filter(enumInstance -> enumInstance.name().equalsIgnoreCase(source.trim())).
                                              findFirst().
                                              orElse(null);
    }
}
```

where `Converter` belongs to the package `org.springframework.core.convert.converter` and the two class annotations belong to the package `org.springframework.data.convert`.

And then in your `@Configuration` file, just register the same as:

```
@Bean
public CustomConversions customConversions() {
    List<Converter<?, ?>> converterList = new ArrayList<>();
    converterList.add(new YourEnumWriteConverter());
    converterList.add(new YourEnumReadConverter());
    return new CustomConversions(converterList);
}
```

where `CustomConversions` belong to `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert`

This should solve your problem. One important thing to note here is, if you want all the enums in your application or maybe a particular set of enums present in your application to be persisted as lowercase, I would suggest to write `ConverterFactory` instead of individually writing a pair of `Converter`s for each such enum. This answer is already long, so not writing about setting up `ConverterFactory`

Some links that will be helpful:

[Mongo Custom Converters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongo/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.custom-converters)

[Spring Type Conversion](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.11.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#core-convert)

[Another useful SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385920/spring-mongodb-storing-retrieving-enums-as-int-not-string)