# Bind a String value to an enum in a @RequestBody entity in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot to write a web service. I have an entity `Animal` and an enum `Kind` that can be either `Kind.DOG` or `Kind.CAT`. The `Animal` class contains `private Kind kind` as one of its instance variables. When I make an HTTP request, I pass in a string value for `kind` and when the request maps to the header:

`@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/create")
 public ResponseEntity<Animal> createAnimal(@RequestBody Animal animal)`

I want `kind` to be internally converted to `Kind.DOG`/`Kind.CAT` if I am passed in either "dog" or "cat". Right now, if I pass in `DOG` or `CAT`, it works fine but if's lowercase it doesn't. Can someone tell me what to do? I tried the following:

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder dataBinder) {
    dataBinder.registerCustomEditor(Kind.class, new KindEnumConverter());
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/create")
public ResponseEntity<Animal> createAnimal(@RequestBody Animal animal)
```

and

```
public class KindEnumConverter extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        setValue(Kind.valueOf(text.toUpperCase()));
    }

}
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Take a look at the accepted answer from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39774427/springs-requestparam-with-enum

Comment: I tried both solutions but I think the difference is that their enum is a direct `@RequestParam` but for me, it's an instance of the `@RequestBody`.

Comment: Then try looking into this. Same Issue as yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33637427/spring-requestbody-and-enum-value

Answer (score -1):

`InitBinder` won't work with `@RequestBody` as per my experience.
We use Spring Boot and the way I solved this problem is, I excluded all the jackson related dependencies from `spring-boot-starter-web`, so that I can use latest jackson.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

And then I added the latest jackson dependencies as:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Now that we have the new jackson library we can just set this in the `application.properties` file:
`spring.jackson.mapper.accept_case_insensitive_enums=true`

In case you use YAML, then:

```
spring:
  jackson:
    mapper:
      accept_case_insensitive_enums: true
```

Inspiration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44217670/1781024